# unable to load image in xamarin forms - Windows XAML

Tags: xamarin, mobile

0

code is - in xamarin -

in code behind var image = new Image { Source = "//Assets//food.jpg" };

image is not loadind in actual xamarin form.

i need for the xamarin forms right now not ios android letter for android ios

right now iam trying for windows xamarin only which folder do i need for windows xamarin.

Comment: have you read the docs?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#local-images

Answer (score 0):

In `Universal Windows Platform (UWP)` - By default, images should be placed in the application's root directory with `Build Action`: `Content`. Alternatively, images can be placed in a different directory which is then specified with a platform-specific. For more information, see [Default image directory on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/windows/default-image-directory).

You could refer to this [sample code](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/main/WorkingWithImages/WorkingWithImages.UWP).